# Dynamically substitute Blazor component in HTML string

Tags: c#, dynamic, blazor, blazor-client-side

I would like to dynamically replace a Blazor client-side component inside some HTML text that I receive from a service.

For example let's say that I receive the following string:

```
string htmlText = @"
<h1>Heading with {my component} inside it</h1>
";
```

I would like to replace all the text within the curly brackets with the component `MyComponent`, which takes a parameter `Text` and renders as `<em>@Text</em>`.

In the end what I would want to obtain is:

```
<h1>Heading with <em>my component</em> inside it</h1>
```

The closest I got was by splitting the string into parts that are HTML and parts that should be replaced with the component (like so: `SplitText = htmlText.Split('{', '}');`) and then rendering them in a for loop inside the Blazor page:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < SplitText.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        @((MarkupString)SplitText[i])
    }
    else
    {
        <MyComponent Text="@SplitText[i]" />
    }
}
```

However this renders in Chrome as:

```
<h1>Heading with </h1>
<em>my component</em>
inside it
```

I tried also using `RenderFragment` however I ended up obtaining similar results.

**Edit:**

I'll add some context to clarify a bit what I'm trying to do. Also there might be some better approach that I haven't thought of and maybe explaining a bit the purpose of this could help somebody pointing me in a better direction.

This is aimed at building a web application where users could write their own notes (sort of) using a rich editor that will output HTML (or Markdown maybe). The editor will also allow to insert some special tags to link to other notes written by them. These are the curly brackets from the example. The text will be stored in a database and validated beforehand, so there is no risk of having to deal with broken syntax (e.g. HTML tags within curly brackets or nested curly brackets). When the text will be rendered, the special tags should be replaced by the component in question, which generates the links and handles some more functionalities (e.g. popping up the note's preview on mouse over). So it will be more complex than just adding `<em>` tags as seen in the example.

I reckon this could be done fairly easily with JavaScript, but first I wanted to see whether it was possible to do it with pure Blazor, since it is such an interesting new framework.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It will be more than just an heading, mostly paragraphs with formatting in them. There won't be any weird stuff like your example, as the text will be validated. I've added some context to the question, probably should have done that from the beginning, sorry.

Comment: Please if you got solutions told me

Comment: Interesting idea, please told me if you got solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using MarkupString is a bit tricky, as the Blazor engine will close tags automatically, and ignore closing tags with no related opening tags. That is how you are getting the output you see above.

Since the service is providing the string with tags included, you can provide it to the component along with the inner text and do some intelligent string work to get a markup string that will render correctly.

**MyComponent.razor**

```cs
@if (MarkupText != null )
{
    @((MarkupString)$"{FirstHalf}{InnerText}{SecondHalf}")
}

@code{

    [Parameter] public string MarkupText { get; set; }

    // Inner Text set with starting value, can be left blank if needed
    [Parameter] public string InnerText { get; set; } = "";

    public string FirstHalf => MarkupText.Substring(0, MarkupText.IndexOf("{"));
    public string SecondHalf => MarkupText.Substring(MarkupText.IndexOf("}") + 1);
}
```

Then to use it with your htmlText from above:

```cs
<MyComponent MarkupText="@htmlText" InnerText="<em>Something</em>" />
```

The output for this becomes:

**Heading with *Something* inside it**

This is a simple version that should give you the idea, but the key point is you want to set up the markup string as one continuous string, and then cast it to `MarkupString` in one shot, so the compiler places tags correctly. Using this same method, you could expand the above idea do some really heavy string manipulation and build things up as much as you want.

As a side note, if the service could provide only the text with the curly braces and no tags, you could very easily construct nested components with the `RenderFragment` concept as well, and you would have better separation between content and presentation. By receiving a string with no tags and then splitting it just like I show it, you would only need to have an outer component that took the string, split it, and placed the first and second parts accordingly around a child component, and Blazor would render it all the way you would expect, no MarkupString required at all. The  tags would be in the outer component instead. Not sure how much control over that service output you have, but it's something to think about.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and for explaining the MarkupString problem, I had a feeling it was something like that. Unfortunately however I don't think this solution would fit my case, as the HTML rendered by the component will be more complex that that and the component needs to be able to handle events as well. I forgot to mention that in my question, sorry. I've edited it and added some context to clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The component is not the problem, the 'user defined' HTML is.

You can't embed a component in a MarkupString. You will need to build a RenderFragment. But you can't just use  2 MarkupString's for the before and after that component. You can't break the tags (like `<h1>` in your example) that way.

So the only route I can see is to parse the HTML, build a RenderTree while replacing the {mycomponent} fields in the lowest level text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't know how to handle your razor-component html-tags like `<MyComponent/>`. You can't convert it to a string, feed it to the browser and get this to work. It's the Blazor-component itself that generates actual browser-understable html-tags etc. So you still need Blazor to generate the HTML for razor-components you are using.

You could use a renderfragment instead if that is applicable to your situation.

In your render section:

```
@ReplaceMyParameter("foo {my component} bar")
```

In your code section:

```
RenderFragment ReplaceMyParameter(string t)
{
    var s = t.Split("{my component}");
    return@<text>
        @s.First()
        <MyComponent/>
        @s.LastOrDefault()
    </text>;
}
```